# Setting mix-blend-mode to anything but "normal" will hide element in Chrome on Android 9

Tags: android, css, google-chrome, android-9.0-pie, mix-blend-mode

CSS' mix-blend-mode seems to fail on Android 9:

- Chrome
- Webview in Cordova (also Chrome in that case, probably)

It works on:

- Chrome on Android 8
- Firefox on Android 9

I initially experienced the issue with an SVG element, but I am also able to reproduce it with some simple divs.

A very simple code example:
https://codepen.io/walmink/pen/YoJRqa

I tried to run the example below and get the expected result on a Nexus 5 running Android 8 (left), but it fails on a OnePlus 6 phone running Android 9 (right) ([see image](https://ibb.co/WFYBqX3)). I've had other users (of a game of mine that uses mix-blend-mode) report the same issue on a OnePlus 7 and a Google Pixel 3a XL running Android 9.

It also seems to work fine on any desktop browser I've tried. On Safari, it will blend with the background as well unless you add `isolation: isolate`, but at least the blending still happens.

Comment: Possibly related to this Chrome bug report: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=961581&q=%22mix-blend-mode%22&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

Comment: Pretty sure this is fixed now?   I just stumbled onto a random demo with `mix-blend-mode` working without any workarounds, so I checked the other tests and everything looks good! Not sure when it happened, as I autoupdate, but I'm on 77.0.3865.73

Comment: That is good news! Do you know if Chrome updates are passed on to phones independently of OS updates, or if the browser is baked into the OS updates (like iOS)? Asking because if baked into OS updates, I wonder how long it would take before it would make its way into all the vendor's own versions of Android.

Answer (score 4):

Thank you for tracking down that Chrome issue! I've been debugging this all day but missed that one. I'm on a OnePlus 6t. Someone else wasn't able to reproduce on a Pixel 2, but glad to hear it is in fact happening on other devices.

**I have a workaround**, which I'll also address in that Chromium thread, soon.

- Option 1: Force hardware acceleration on the blended element, using something like `transform: translate3d(0,0,0);`
- Option 2: On the blended element, add a `will-change` property, set to pretty much anything. `will-change: opacity;` for example, would suffice. This forced re-paint seems to be enough to kick the blend-mode back into gear.

Now, this fixes the problem... but causes another. If you have to do any scrolling more than about one more page length, the blended element will eventually get cut off, and will remain invisible for the rest of the page.

This behavior (or similar) is described here:

- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=798148
  This one sounds almost identical, but but is marked as fixed.
- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=992398 This one also sounds similar, but they've identified as being related to the max size of a layer, which is fairly large (some 8000px). Whereas the behavior you'll find with this workaround, is more like 2000px, or roughly 200% of the height of the viewport (hard to test).

Unfortunately this cut off content behavior is very consistent... That Pixel 2 user I mentioned before, that couldn't reproduce the initial blend-mode issue, **was** seeing this cut off once the workarounds were applied.

You said you're making a game though, so hopefully there's not much scrolling involved?

Also, for what it's worth, you may find the screen blend mode is exempt from all this and may still work without any workarounds.

You can test with this https://codepen.io/chasebank/pen/wvwWGxd  The workarounds are commented out in the `.box` element.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for sharing your workaround! I upvoted it because it works, but unfortunately only partly, and not for me. I tried the `will-change` before but it doesn't seem to work for SVG elements (which my game is made with). I've updated my [Codepen](https://codepen.io/walmink/pen/YoJRqa) to prove it. I hope to find a workaround that will work for SVG too.

Comment: Curiously, I just discovered that the "lighten" blend mode I use in the game (and is part of the puzzle's mechanic) can actually be substituted by "screen" to the same effect! Thanks for pointing out that "screen" blend mode worked.

Comment: Ah that sucks about SVG. I was working with some when I found this bug, but I think I didn't notice that issue because I was already using a workaround for the workaround? LOL This is sort of hacky, but totally valid... Just depends on how bad you need this fixed/how complex the SVGs are. If you can convert all blended SVGs to normal DIVs, and embed the SVG as an encoded data URI background-image, you can use the blend mode on the DIV and the will-change/3d transform fix will work. It's more complex markup, but you retain the vector quality of the SVG https://codepen.io/chasebank/pen/xxKOMLy